# Do dwellers in production rooms level up faster if I play more actively?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have an objective to *Level up 24 Dwellers*. This will take some time. I am wondering about the guys in my production rooms. Every once in a while they get XP and they will level up eventually. But is the given XP based solely on the fact that they are in the room, or does them working vs standing arround while the resources have not been collected make a difference?

So will they gain more XP and level faster if I spend more time in the game, thus collecting more resources?

Comment: My experience with the game says yes as I couldn't play for a day or 2, my dwellers wouldn't level up all at the same time when coming back to the game. It does seem to depend on either the time played in the game or the number of resources gathered.

Comment: I have the same experience as @JonathanDrapeau - A lot of things seem to grind to a halt when not playing: Leveling, resource consumption and raids.

Comment: @Lobo Raids are explicitly mentioned in the help and load screens. Resource consumption continues for a little while but stops. But training and exploring continues. Dwellers that are exploring will level up when not in the game (though they don't give caps). But gaining XP from working in production rooms is not covered in the help afaict.

Comment: [ definitive answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258837/do-dwellers-level-up-faster-in-crafting-rooms) Crafting rooms and exploring are very fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dwellers get XP in three ways:

- A small amount from working in a room. This is continuous and will happen even if the game is 'off' but it is very slow.
- A medium amount from Rushing (succeed or fail) a room.
- A large amount from exploring the wastes.

It's worth noting that each dweller leveling up will only count for the objective once, so if you send a Level 1 Dweller into the wastes, she won't accomplish the goal for you by herself even if she gets to level 23.

One possible solution is to have several single width rooms, put two people you want to level up in the first one, and rush it until they level up. Being a small room, the failures will be easy to deal with. Once they level up, run them through a gauntlet of your other rooms with low chance of failure to bring their happiness back up. Then select your next two level up candidates, put them in the first room and rush until they level up. Hopefully by the time they have the other rooms will have "cooled down" and you can rush them once or twice in each to bring their happiness back up to acceptable levels. Every success/failure increases or decreases happiness by 10%, but happiness won't go below 10% so 9 successful rushes in a row will bring anyone back to 100%. In practice I'd probably be okay with getting my "levelers" back to 60-90% and let them get to 100% again later.

Of course if you don't have the budget to build a bunch of easily rushable rooms, or your dwellers aren't trained well enough to recover happiness you might find it easier just to send 24 folks off into the wastes until they level up.