# Do dwellers level up faster in crafting-rooms?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I started crafting a legendary weapon in the "Weapon Workshop" and put several full stat dwellers in there. The dwellers were all at Level 40 - 50 and I noticed that pretty much every dweller leveled up during the crafting process. That leads me to the question, if there's actually a higher experience gain in these rooms, compared to "regular" production-rooms?

I was also wondering, if the type of item (common, rare, legendary) had any influence on the amount of experience gained?

Comment: Full stat dweller levels up to 50 in one full (60h or so) raid of wasteland.

Comment: @Nakilon Ok, that's not the question though ;)

Comment: That's why that comment is not the answer ..) I just said that if I was interested in leveling up, I would just sent them out.

Comment: I just built these rooms today, and I also noticed the dwellers leveling up pretty fast (assuming they have something to work on). Could perhaps quantify it by getting two identical dwellers ready and assigning one to the crafting room and one to a regular production room.

Answer (score 18):

Ok, so I finally gave this a go. Here are my findings.

Trained 4 dwellers to max. stats at level 1. Meet our 4 heroes:

[image: the 4 heroes]

All are equipped with a *Heavy Wasteland Gear* (to get max HP gain per Level-up).

- **Mr. Worker**: He will be working in a Nuka Cola Plant with 5 other Dwellers
- **Mr. Wasteland**: His task is to roam the wastelands
- **Mr. Soloworker**: He well be working in a Nuka-Cola Bottler on its own
- **Mr. Outfitter**: He well be working in an outfit plant all by himself, building a T-60F Power Armor.

Here are the stats after ~1 hour (Levels: 3, 2, 3, 4):

[image: stats after ~1 hour]

After ~10 hours (Levels: 13, 7, 13, 6):

[image: stats after ~10 hours]

After ~15 hours (Levels: 17, 8, 19, 7):

[image: stats after ~15 hours]

As you can see, the experience gain in crafting rooms seems to be *at least double* the amount you get from normal production rooms.

The levels of the dwellers that remained in the vault could potentially be even higher, because they stop gaining experience once they level up (you'll have to click them to continue). And I'm sure I wasted some precious time by not opening the game at exactly the right moments. I guess this also explains the discrepancy between the two dwellers in production rooms…

**Conclusion:** Experience gain is really good in crafting rooms. So best stick dwellers in there that aren't at level 50 yet. It's no alternative to leveling in the wasteland though, because you'll have to babysit the dwellers (clicking them to level up) and the experience gain doesn't ramp up like the experience gained in the wasteland.

Comment: I'm interested to see if making common,rare or legendary items will make any difference in leveling.

Comment: The trade off is that you still have to wait the 50% "return time" when your explorer gets up to the level that you want. So if you're touching the game every once in a while - the outfitter is going to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that in production room experience is only gained when you are online (actually playing the game - it will max to the production time of your room say 5 mins for power generation etc) unlike wasteland or crafting which is something that is running even when you are not playing. It is this mechanic that is giving the impression that production room experience is way less.